# sympyの連結の使い方を教えて下さい

Tags: python, sympy

sympyの連結の使い方を教えて下さい

```
from sympy import *
var('x a b')
f=a*(2*x**2 - 1) + 4*x**3 + x*(b - 3)
p = Poly(f, x)
colors = p.all_coeffs()
print(colors)
for i in range(len(colors)):
    print(colors[i] +"*X**" + str(len(colors)-i-1))
#WANT 4*x**3+2*a*x**2+(b-3)*x-a
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Integer' and 'str'
```

(参考)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy
http://kesin.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/05/12/004541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poly 型のインスタンス(多項式)を評価すれば、一応、項の次数順に表示されます。

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x a b')
>>> f = a*(2*x**2 - 1) + 4*x**3 + x*(b - 3)
>>> p = Poly(f, x)
>>> p
Poly(4*x**3 + 2*a*x**2 + (b - 3)*x - a, x, domain='ZZ[a,b]')
```

なので、式部分だけを取り出したいのであれば、`str(p)` の結果を加工しても良いかもしれません。

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('^Poly\((.+?),', str(p)).group(1)
'4*x**3 + 2*a*x**2 + (b - 3)*x - a'
```

ところで、Poly 型インスタンスの内容を表示しているのは、以下のメソッドです。

**sympy/printing/str.py**

```
def _print_Poly(self, expr):
    terms, gens = [], [ self._print(s) for s in expr.gens ]

    for monom, coeff in expr.terms():
              :
```

ここからコードをコピーして適当に変更すれば目的の関数を作成できます。

※ 以下の関数は単項式(monomial)のみに対応しています。

**monomial_as_ordered function**

```
from sympy import *

def monomial_as_ordered(p):
  terms, gen = [], str(p.gens[0])

  for monom, coeff in p.terms():
    s_monom = []

    for i, exp in enumerate(monom):
      if exp > 0:
        if exp == 1:
          s_monom.append(gen)
        else:
          s_monom.append(gen + "**%d" % exp)

    s_monom = "*".join(s_monom)

    if coeff.is_Add:
      if s_monom:
        s_coeff = "(" + str(coeff) + ")"
      else:
        s_coeff = str(coeff)
    else:
      if s_monom:
        if coeff is S.One:
          terms.extend(['+', s_monom])
          continue

        if coeff is S.NegativeOne:
          terms.extend(['-', s_monom])
          continue

      s_coeff = str(coeff)

    if not s_monom:
      s_term = s_coeff
    else:
      s_term = s_coeff + "*" + s_monom

    if s_term.startswith('-'):
      terms.extend(['-', s_term[1:]])
    else:
      terms.extend(['+', s_term])

  if terms[0] in ['-', '+']:
    modifier = terms.pop(0)
    if modifier == '-':
      terms[0] = '-' + terms[0]

  return ' '.join(terms)
```

**実行**

```
>>> print(monomial_as_ordered(p))
4*x**3 + 2*a*x**2 + (b - 3)*x - a
```

念の為に申し添えて置くと、この関数の戻り値は文字列であって Poly 型のインスタンスではありません。